CUDA code not working for advent of code 2024 day 17 part 2
I have tried to bruteforce part two of this problem using cuda.
If you are not logged in or haven’t done part 1, in part 2, we have to find the lowest value for register A (with the other registers set to 0 initially) so that the program outputs itself. We have to create a quine.
I am very new to cuda and this is what i have come up with. After 10 minutes, the program outputs nothing and stops. The program works correctly on the sample data.
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

__device__ uintmax_t
do_combo(uintmax_t i, uintmax_t A, uintmax_t B, uintmax_t C)
{
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        return i;
    case 4:
        return A;
    case 5:
        return B;
    case 6:
        return C;
    }
    return i;
};

__global__ void
cuda()
{

    enum instructions_names {
        adv,
        bxl,
        bst,
        jnz,
        bxc,
        out,
        bdv,
        cdv
    };

    uintmax_t instructions[16] = { 2, 4, 1, 7, 7, 5, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 5, 5, 3, 0 };
    uintmax_t i_len = 16;

    /* uintmax_t instructions[6] = {0,3,5,4,3,0}; */
    /* uintmax_t i_len = 6; */
    uintmax_t output[16];
    uintmax_t output_len = 0;
    uintmax_t step = 10000 * (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
    uintmax_t stop = step + 10000;

    for (; step < stop; step++) {
        output_len = 0;
        uintmax_t A = step;
        uintmax_t B = 0;
        uintmax_t C = 0;

        for (uintmax_t i = 0; i < i_len; i += 2) {
            if (output_len > 16)
                return;
            switch (instructions[i]) {
            case adv:
                {
                    /* takes combo operand, divides A by 2^it into B */
                    A = A >> do_combo(instructions[i + 1], A, B, C);
                    continue;
                }
            case bxl:
                {
                    /* takes literal operand, XORs B and it into B */
                    B = B ^ instructions[i + 1];
                    continue;
                }
            case bst:
                {
                    /* takes combo operand, modulo 8 into B */
                    B = do_combo(instructions[i + 1], A, B, C) % 8;
                    continue;
                }
            case jnz:
                {
                    /* takes literal operand, jumps to it if non null */
                    if (A == 0)
                        continue;
                    i = instructions[i + 1] - 2;
                    continue;
                }
            case bxc:
                {
                    /* ignores operand, XOR B and C into B */
                    B = B ^ C;
                    continue;
                }
            case out:
                {
                    /* takes combo operand, outputs it modulo 8 */
                    output[output_len++] = do_combo(instructions[i + 1], A, B, C) % 8;
                    continue;
                }
            case bdv:
                {
                    /* takes combo operand, divides A by 2^it into B */
                    B = A >> do_combo(instructions[i + 1], A, B, C);
                    continue;
                }
            case cdv:
                {
                    /* takes combo operand, divides A by 2^it into C */
                    C = A >> do_combo(instructions[i + 1], A, B, C);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (i_len != output_len)
            return;

        for (uintmax_t i = 0; i < i_len; i++) {
            if (instructions[i] != output[i])
                return;
        }

        printf("%lu\n", step);
        asm("trap;");
    }
}

int
main()
{
    unsigned int threads = 1024;
    unsigned int all = 300000000000 / threads;

    cuda<<<all,threads>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();

    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
    }
}

I tried asking chatgpt what’s wrong with my code but it just says nonsense.

blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x goes up to 30,000,000. And then you multiply that by 100,000,000. The computation 100000000*(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) easily exceeds the range of unsigned int (which is what blockIdx etc are). Assigning them to uintmax_t is not enough. You have to do the computation in uintmax_t, too, to avoid intermediate wrap-arounds

How could i do this?

100000000 * std::uintmax_t { blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x }

Sadly that doesn’t change anything.

I tried asking chatgpt what’s wrong with my code but it just says nonsense. This at least is completely expected.

Yeah it’s not been helpfull once. It seems you need to know the answer to what you ask it to make it produce anything usefull, which is then useless.

I have edited my code to limit the number of iteration per kernel, and it has now been running for some time. I’ll edit my post accordingly.

After 10 minutes of running it has stopped without any output.

For me it runs to completion within seconds. It just doesn't print any output since the equality check is never satisfied. But the length check is and moving the print before that point does generate output

BTW: I'm not sure your logic makes much sense. Most steps will never be tested because you have an if (output_len > 16) return; in the innermost loop that terminates early. Similarly at the end of the loop

I do believe my logic is sound because it works on the sample input (which is 0,3,5,4,3,0 and that i have commented out here). No instruction removes output inside a step. That is why if the output is above 16 characters the program will never output itself.

Well, if you say so. But then what's the point of the outer loop? If the inner loop finishes, you either return if i_len != output_len or you return if any instructions[i] != output[i] or you trap after printing. I don't see any code path with which the outer loop is executed more than once.

You’re right! thank you for the feedback, this is a leftover of when i only did one iteration per kernel, i’ll replace the returns by continues and rerun
